# Get strikes from delta works with put but no with call function

Tags: black-scholes, greeks, delta

From call-put parity one can derive that $\Delta_C - \Delta_P = 1$. We also know that $\Delta_C = e^{-qt}N(d_1)$. If $e^{-qt} = 0.85$ then there is no value for $d_1$ for a $\Delta_C = 0.9$ as $ 0 <= N(d_1) <= 1 $. Therefore there is no way to get a strike with $\Delta_C = 0.9$.

But from the first equation, we have that if $\Delta_C = 0.9$ then $\Delta_P = -0.1$. Also from the delta of a Put equation we have $-0.1 = -0.85N(-d_1) $ -> $0.1176 = N(-d_1)$.

This second equation does yield a result for $d_1$ and therefore a strike.

If put-call parity holds, why can't I get a result (and also same result) with $\Delta_C = 0.9$ instead of $\Delta_P = -0.1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have dividends, then $\Delta_C - \Delta_P = e^{-qt}$. As you note, you have $\Delta_C = e^{-qt}N(d_1)$ and $\Delta_P = e^{-qt}(N(d_1)-1)$.

For both $\Delta_C$ and $\Delta_P$ you then get $N(d_1)\approx 1.0588$.

[1] https://bookdown.org/maxime_debellefroid/MyBook/the-greeks.html, Section 5.2.5 Delta under Black-Scholes

Comment: Everything makes sense again, thank you.